# How to change kernel Timer frequency

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, kernel

I have a question about changing kernel frequency.

I compiled kernel by using:

```
        make menuconfig(do some changes in config)
        (under Processor type and features->Timer frequency to change frequency)
        1.fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-mm kernel-image kernel-headers
        2.export CONCURRENCY_LEVEL=3
        3.sudo dpkg -i linux-image-3.2.14-mm_3.2.14-mm-10.00.Custom_amd64.deb
        4.sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.2.14-mm_3.2.14-mm-10.00.Custom_amd64.deb
```

then say if I want to change the frequency of kernel,

what I did is:

```
        I replaced .config file with my own config file
        (since I want to do this automatically without opening make menuconfig ui)
```

then I repeat the step1,2,3,4 again

Is there anyway I do not need repeat the above 4 steps?

Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: What does "changing kernel frequency" mean?

Comment: @Celada Probably the timer frequency (CONFIG_HZ).

Comment: Hi, sorry for a little unclear, I meant timer frequency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timer frequency is fixed in Linux (unless you build a tickless kernel - CONFIG_NO_HZ=y - but the upper limit will still be fixed). You cannot change it at runtime or at boot time. You can only change it at compile time.

So the answer is: no. You need to rebuild the kernel when you want to change it.

Answer (score -1):

The kernel timer frequency (`CONFIG_HZ`) is *not* configurable at runtime - you *will* have to compile a new kernel when you change the setting and you *will* have to reboot the system with the new kernel to see the effects of any change.

If you are doing this a lot, though, you should be able to create a little shell script to automate the kernel configure/build/install process. For example it should not be too hard to automate the procedure so that e.g.

```
./kernel-prep-with-hz 100
```

would rebuild and install a new kernel, only requiring from you to issue the final reboot command.

Keep in mind though, that the timer frequency may subtly affect various subsystems in unpredictable ways, although things have become a lot better since the tickless timer code was introduced.

Why do you want to do this anyway?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this will help. As the articale says, you can change the frequency between the available frequency that your system supports. ([Check if CPUfreq is already enabled in your system](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-cpufreq-1/))

Example, mine.

```
#cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies  
2000000 1667000 1333000 1000000
#echo 1000000 > cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq
```

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-cpufreq-2/

Comment: That's the CPU frequency, not the timer frequency.